# Where was scala_home homebrew installed on OSX?

Tags: scala, bash

I can't get scalac working despite `scala` successfully opening `scala>` in the terminal. 
I suspect this is something to do with setting scala_home in my `.bash_profile`, on my mac.
[image: current bash_profile]
What is the correct value for `SCALA_HOME`, or how do I find that correct value? (it was homebrewed)

And is the method to scale-compile the following:
[image]
to cd into the lower `src` folder and `scalac IntroducingScala.HelloWorld.scala`?

Answer (score 9):

Homebrew usually tells you where it installs if you do `brew info <name>`. It's usually points at `/usr/local/opt/<name>`, which will be a symlink to the current version you're running.

When I run `brew info scala` it also comes with a helpful caveat:

```
==> Caveats
To use with IntelliJ, set the Scala home to:
/usr/local/opt/scala/idea
```

Comment: thanks @colinjwebb :) whenever opened terminal informs me `/usr/local/opt/scala/idea` (brew came up with that on mine too) is a directory. 
If i extend this address down to `scala-compiler.jar` I get a permission denied. 
If i ignore terminal and try and compile it seems to create a package+class within the package+class. 
What do you think is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

we can usually know the path using below:

```
which scala
```